# Objective-C - Need to know how to add another target to a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I have 2 classes(FirstClass and SecondClass). FirstClass is a UIViewController, and secondClass is a NSObject class. In the FirstClass i have a button -- dialButton.

In the SecondClass, I call a method that I made in the FirstClass (changeMethod)

This Method changes the Method that the button will call when clicked. The Method it changes to is a method in the SecondClass (secondClassMethod).

This changeMethod does exactly this:

```
[dialButton addTarget:secondClass selector:@selector(secondClassMethod)         
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

By the way, dialButton is a static button. What am I doing wrong

Edit: I fixed the problem above, but now my problem is this:

The button's target method is changed, but the target method isn't called.

I call the method printPrompt from the SecondClass.

printPrompt:

```
FirstClass *firstClass =[[FirstClass alloc]init];
[firstClass test];
```

test:

```
SecondClass *secondClass = [[SecondClass alloc]init];
[dialButton removeTarget:self selector:@selector(firstClassMethod) forControlEvent: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[dialButton addTarget:secondClass selector:@selector(secondClassMethod)         
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

secondClassMethod is not called when i click the button after calling test.. rather, the program crashes.

secondClassMethod:
FirstClass *firstClass = [[FirstClass alloc]init];
[firstClass setString: @"Test"];

setString just changes a UIText Field. I've tested it and setString: works.

---

Comment: And the observed behaviour is what? If nothing happens, check the state of dialButton when the addTarget: message is sent. Could be nil.

Comment: How do i check the state of dialButton? @AdamEberbach

Comment: Is it nil or not? Sending a message to nil is fine but it does nothing. If your button does nothing, perhaps it did not exist at the time you set its target.

Comment: how do you check if it is nil? @AdamEberbach

Comment: Set a breakpoint on it and look at it in the debugger.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very advanced with programming.. Set a breakpoint where? Which line? And where is the debugger?@AdamEberbach

Comment: Time to read some basics, please take the time to do some tutorials - start with http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 which is a good introduction to the debugger and breakpoints.

Comment: And just to be sure.. the targetActions is nil.. that's what im looking for right? @AdamEberbach

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted will add an additional target/action to the button. Buttons can call multiple methods in multiple targets when they are tapped.

If you want to replace an existing target/action with another one, you have to first remove the existing target/action using the `removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method, then add the new target/action with the code you posted.

Comment: Ok... I did that, but now it still does not seem to call the method when it is clicked. Added more code. See if you can help

Comment: post the method headers for firstClass and secondClass. I'm guessing that you got the method signature for your secondClassMethod IBAction method wrong.

Comment: Umm, nope. I don't see the headers for FirstClass and SecondClass.

Comment: Oh the actual class.. Do you want the .h file then?

Comment: If you could refer to the comments on my actual post. My button is nil.. how do i make it not nil?